# sed regex replace part of file name

Tags: bash, filesystems

Went thru sed tutorials but can't figure out how to use.

Have 100s of files across sub folders that are like 'ABCxxx.ext' need to rename to 'XYZxxx.ext'

Where xxx are differnt alpha numberic strings and .ext is any extention (xml, java, xls)

I'm able to use :

```
find . -iname "ABC*.*"
```

In terminal, To view these files, but not sure what sed or other command to use to rename the files. On Mac 10.9.4

Examples:
"Abc01k.xls" ==> "Xyz01k.xls"
"Abcloans.xml" ==> "Xyzloans.xml"
"AbcThreads.java" ==> "XyzThreads.java"

So if name of file has Abc chars in it, replace that with Xyz. Can be first characters or inside.

Read : https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131164/how-to-tag-files-with-finder-tags-using-parts-of-a-file-name

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75114/any-easy-way-to-search-for-replace-characters-in-jpg-file-names-in-a-folder

The last 1 works for 1 folder but I want it to visit all folders.

bash script :

```
for i in Abc*; do
      mv "$i" "${i/Abc/Xyz}"
done
```

How can I call this script for all sub folders? Or how to do same with sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var1=`find . -type f -iname '*ABC*'`
for i in $var1; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/ABC/ZXC/g'`"; done
```

This will rename files inside subdirectories, and change "ABC" to "ZXC" even in the middle of filename.

Comment: Do i put that in a script and call with bash or sh? Or directly paste in to terminal?

Comment: You can pyt it in a script or call it in Terminal. That's two lines. You can make it one by adding ";" after first command

Comment: Does not work if ABC case changes. anyway to tell sed to be case insenstive? tried  ... sed 's/Tfw/Ddt/gI'`";   got error. Your script in a file, 2 lines

Comment: You can change `sed` command to: `perl -pe 's/ABC/ZXC/gi'`. But this will always change "abc" (case insensitive) strings to capital "ZXC".

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find . -iname "ABC*.*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; mv "$f" "${f/Abc/Xyz}"' - {} \;
```

Comment: +1 This worked too thanks, but not case insensitive. Like sed way as want to learn that command too.

Comment: For ignore case match `shopt -s nocasematch` and `shopt -s nocaseglob` before this `find` to make it ignore case.